# iPHone ATMHud - Update text

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Using the ATM Hud project on an iPhone, how do I get the text to update on a HUD that is up and displaying?

I have tried the Update method after changing the Caption text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm playing around with ATMHud too. 
There is a little tutorial here showing some uses of it.

[ATMHud Examples](http://dlinsin.github.com/2011/03/24/ATMHud.html)

*ArQ*